# Converting vector of floats to hex/binary string

Tags: c++, vector, floating-point, hex, gsoap

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13935718/8137084) answer about encoding/decoding to base 64, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022099/convert-float-vector-to-byte-vector-and-back) answer about converting from float to byte vector and back, I was trying to convert a float vector to a hex or binary string.

This is my code:

```
vector<float> floats = ...;
const unsigned char* bytes = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&floats[0]);
std::vector<unsigned char> byteVec(bytes, bytes + sizeof(float) * floats.size());
std::cout<<byteVec.size()<<std::endl;
std::string dat = base64_encode(&byteVec[0], byteVec.size());
std::vector<unsigned char> decodedData = base64_decode(dat);
std::cout<<decodedData.size()<<std::endl;
unsigned char* bytesN = &(decodedData[0]);    // point to beginning of memory
float* floatArray = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytesN);
std::vector<float> floatVec(floatArray, floatArray + sizeof(unsigned char) * decodedData.size());   
std::cout<<floatVec.size()<<std::endl;
```

The original vector, floats, is 262,144 floats, and both cout statements print 1048576, and then the program segfaults. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a better or faster method to accomplish this? I want to send the string using xml/gsoap, so if gsoap has a function to do this automatically, it would make my life a lot easier.

Comment: `unsigned char* bytesN = &(decodedData[0]); float* floatArray = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bytesN);` - It is undefined to reinterpret a block of `char`s as another type. It violates aliasing rules. Only the converse is allowed. You should `memcpy` the bytes into an actual, declared & allocated, array of `floats` & then read that. Even that is brittle as you are making assumptions about how the implementation represents `float` & whether that matches the one that encoded them. Also, there could be other problems; it's hard to read this solid lump of code. Some newlines and comments would be nice.

Comment: So you have one vector of `float` elements. For every element you want to hex-encode it into a string in a new vector? And then decode the new vector into a second vector of `float`? That's as simple as two calls to [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude well, I want the whole vector to be one hex string, not a new vector of other strings. Would transform still work for that?

Comment: Or do you want to create a single hex-encoded string of *all* elements in the vector, and then convert them back into a second vector?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yup, the latter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major problem is this:

```
std::vector<float> floatVec(floatArray, floatArray + sizeof(unsigned char) * decodedData.size());
```

Here you say that the number of elements would be `decodedData.size()`, which is `1048576`. But it's wrong since it should only be a quarter of that (because `decodedData.size()` is the size in *bytes* not in the number of `float` elements). This will of course lead to going out of bounds of `decodedData` which leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to divide the size of `decodedData.size()` with `sizeof(float)`:

```
std::vector<float> floatVec(floatArray, floatArray + decodedData.size() / sizeof(float));
```